# How to insert row into 2 tables with a one-to-one relationship in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, one-to-one

Suppose I have 2 tables with a one-to-one relation:

- `tblOrder` (orderId, orderName, totalPrice, billId)
- `tblBill` (billId, billAmount, cardNumber)

The `orderId` in `tblOrder` and `billId` in `tblBill` are the primary key and they are both identity keys. Also `billId` in the `tblOrder` is the unique foreign key.

In the front end using Asp.net, I want the customers to enter the `tblOrder` information first into the database, then I want them to enter `tblBill` information. But I want to automate the process of setting the `billId` foreign key on the `tblOrder`. Problem is when multiple users will use the system at same time how can I know which bill will belong to which order?

One solution I thought of was to insert an empty row in `tblBill` and set that id column value to the `tblOrder`'s `billId` foreign key. And update the bill information when customer enters the bill information in front end. But it doesn't seem like an optimal solution since one empty row insertion will happen for every purchase.

Comment: you can't, you must enter a row into tblBill and then use the autogenerated billId to insert into tblOrder. if you must enter first in tblOrder, that would suggest bill dependent on order, hence remove foreign key from order table and add orderId fk in tblBill

Comment: I understand what you are saying and it does make sense. But I still want to know few things:
 1) if there is this kind of dependency relation between one-to-one tables why doesn't any book or reference address them. I have yet to find a place which says in which table you should include the foreign key. Most says including either one is ok. 
2) I want to look a bit more into this dependency relations . Under what name I most probably likely to find them?

Comment: I would call this 'vertical partitioning'. If this is a one to one relationship then there is no need for the data to be in two tables... unless you wanted to vertically partition them. However there must be some reason you decided to put this info into two tables.